# Site scraping: why am I getting DNS issues after multiple hits?

Tags: c#-4.0, web, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am scraping a site for data every 50-90 seconds randomly using a C# console application running on .net 4.5. There are couple of values I am posting to the site and based off the returned value I kick off some other process. The problem is after say about a thousand hits or so I get what looks like a DNS error. I am trying to sort out what the source of the problem is first, before trying to fix it. Here below are some of the errors I see in my logs:

1. The remote name could not be resolved
2. Unable to connect to the remote server
3. Unexpected character encountered while parsing value <. Path '',
   line 0, position 0.
4. Unable to read data from the transport connection An existing
   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
5. Unable to read data from the transport connection An established
   connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

About 60% of the time I have got the first error. The remaining 40% is divided between the rest of the errors listed above.Are these issues caused by the website I am scraping or by the DNS servers on my end or something else? For all practical purposes the website I am scraping is ok with it as long as I keep the interval between automated hits above 45 seconds which I am doing. The data I am downloading is on an average about 30KB per hit. Please help me understand what could be going wrong and what things I could try to fix this.

Comment: I'd be surprised to see a DNS error if you're hitting the site at 50 to 90 second intervals. The DNS entry should be cached locally. It's possible that the site is blocking you, as suggested by Clint in his answer. It's also possible that you're failing to clean up some resource and after about 1,000 hits your program is experiencing resource exhaustion.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you're running against an automated system designed to protect the site against a DDoS attack http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack.

It's seeing that your same IP address is hitting it repeatedly in a short space of time and is simply blocking your resolution of the eventual server.